# Apache local domain hosting through exposed server

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, firewall, router

Maybe I'm not frasing my question properly, but I have a single IP address and multiple servers behind that IPs router. Is there any way for me to redirect requests from the server getting the HTTP forwards to other computers behind the firewall?

---

I'm using:
Ubuntu - All servers
Apache2 - All servers
IpFire - Router software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with IPFire, take a look at Pound:

http://wiki.ipfire.org/en/addons/pound/start